# Codeigniter HMVC MY_Form_validation from library

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmvc

Whatever I do I cant seem to use the dob function in my MY_Form_validation... please note the _register_verify is inside my User library, and not a controller, so I'm using $CI and not $this...

```
<?php
/** application/libraries/MY_Form_validation **/ 
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public $CI;
    function __construct( $config = array() )
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
        log_message('DEBUG', 'MY FORM VALIDATION Initialized!!');
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function dob($dob)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->form_validation->set_message('dob[]_check', 'Please enter a valid DOB');
        show_error('I AM AN ERROR');
    }
```

This is the function in my User Library...

```
public function _register_verify($testmode = FALSE)
{
    if ($testmode) return TRUE;
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('form_validation');
    $CI->form_validation->CI =& $CI;
    $CI->form_validation->set_rules('dob[]', 'DOB', 'trim|dob');
    if ($CI->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // What to do if user details are NOT correct?
        $CI->session->set_flashdata('dob_error', form_error('dob[]'));
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

I'v tried extending the MY_Form_validation and nothing else and it still doesnt work. And most of the turotials i've found call the form_validation from a controller.

I have checked the log and the log message is not there and no error shows.

EDIT: Managed to get the class initialized, however the dob never gets called

Answer (score 0):

Functions inside of MY_Form_Validation.php should return boolean values that give the outcome of the test.

```
public function dob($dob){
  //not perfect, but, returns true if date matches 12/10/1999 for example.
  return preg_match("/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/", $dob);
}
```

Make sure you've set dob as a rule either in you controller, or in your config file, depending on how you've set things up:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'date of birth', 'required|dob');
```

Errors are handled in `application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php`. Add:

```
$lang['dob'] = "Oops, wrong DOB format.";
```

Lastly, please run your form validations inside your controller, not a library, or model. There is no need to call `get_instance()` and assign to $CI in this use-case.

Comment: Thanks, I just put the validation inside of the user library to keep the controller clean. My problem was that dob cant be passed as an array, eg 'dob[]' wont work but if i do 'dob[day]' it works which means i have to do one each for day, month, year which doesn't really help... is there a better way to validate dob (check it is proper date, not for example 31 Feb) without using javascript.